# React Native: Imports with Class Hierarchy

Tags: class, reactjs, react-native, class-hierarchy

In `react-native`, if one has a class hierarchy of a `Child` who extends the `Parent`, why does the `child` not inherit the `parent`'s imports?

Example:

Parent Class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class ParentClass extends React.Component {

}
```

Child Class:

```
import ParentClass from '../screens/parentclass.js'
export default class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

}
```

The `child` class must re-import `Stylesheet, View, and Alert` in order for them to be usable.

Why does this occur? Is there any way to make the `child` and `parent` classes only have to import a module once?

Comment: Because imports bind to names in the current module's scope...

Comment: So is there any way to have the child class bind the names from the parent module?

Comment: @JakeChasan did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Not yet. Had to reimport in order to get it to work properly. Open to suggestions about a more efficient way to make this work.

Comment: @JakeChasan actually i also din't find any solution.